# Codeigniter ajax request is not working when use external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

My `Codeigniter` ajax request is working when `JS` inner embed. But when i want to use it as external `JS` file. It it not working. Why is that?

View `sample_ajax`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
         <script src='<?= base_url() ?>public/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
         <!--<script src='<?= base_url() ?>public/js/script.js'></script>When put script part on external script.js, it's not working -->       
    </head>
    <body>
         <div>
            <input name="submit1" id="submit1" type="button" value="Load">
        </div>
        <div id="receive" style="height: 50px; background-color: yellowgreen">       
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>' + 'main/testarray',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (retdata) {
                        $("#receive").html(retdata.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>        
    </body> 
</html>
```

Main Controller

```html
class Main extends CI_Controller {
    public function test() { 
        $this->load->view('home/sample_ajax'); 
    } 
    public function testarray() {
        $student_data = [
            'name' => 'Sample Name',
            'age' => '26'
        ];
        echo(json_encode($student_data));
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to echo (json_encode($student_data));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create base url gloabl variable in javascript  in your header or a view that always loading put this code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var baseURL= "<?php echo base_url();?>";
    </script>
```

and url external js file path use this type

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseURL+'main/testarray',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (retdata) {
                        $("#receive").html(retdata.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need ( ) at  echo(json_encode($student_data));

And second you can't just copy

> url: ' php echo base_url();' + 'main/testarray'

to external js, you have to pass base_url() before adding external

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/yourjavascriptexternal.js"></script>
```

It will look like url: base + 'main/testarray'